# What will occur if apt is interrupted during package install?

Tags: apt, files, database

What will happen if, for example, power goes down during package install(I mean unpacking, not dowloading).

Should I avoid such kind of situations or them make no harm, because package database is in consistent state and package could be installed again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid that situation at all costs. While some packages can be easily fixed, others cant be that easily fixed because your computer might stop booting up and other oddities.

So make sure you're actually on a power supply in case of a laptop, or make sure no one messes with the machine while an upgrade is running.

([see as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172983/interrupting-apt-get-dist-upgrade-what-could-happen?rq=1))